# Cartesian product and set operations proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a set and $a$ be a subset of $A$.

Let $B$ be a set and  $b$ be a subset of $B$.

> Prove that: $(a\times b)^c$ = $(a^c \times b) \cup(a \times b^c)$

This equality is true. It was confirmed by my professor and when calculating operations behind sets it works. Nonetheless, I am unable to come up with a proof.

So, far I attempted multiple ideas and different variations.

1) Draw it out and failed. I said, let the Cartesian product of  $A \times B$ be the universe in which  $a \times b$ belongs to. This representation got inaccurate when I had to calculate the complement of $a$ which is in $A$.

2) I tried to prove it algebraically by saying that the Cartesian product of two sets can be viewed as a multiplication where I will have a finite number. For Instance let the set $A$ have $m$ elements, then $a$ has $m - t$ elements and the complement of $a$ is $t$. Likewise the set $B$ has $n$ elements, $b$ has $n-i$ elements and $b$ complement has $i$ elements but my calculations became too abstract.

Comment: like c^2-t^2 ...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x\in (a\times b)^c$. then $x \neq (g,l)$ for any $g\in a,l\in b$.
thus either $g\in A\setminus a$ or $l\in B\setminus b$. there fore $x\in a^c \times B$ or $x\in A \times b^c$. Hense $x\in (a^c \times B)\cup (A \times b^c)$

therefore $(a\times b)^c \subseteq (a^c \times B)\cup (A \times b^c)$

Also if $x\in x\in (a^c \times B)\cup (A \times b^c)$ then $x\in a^c \times B$ or $x\in A \times b^c$. In either cases $x\in (a\times b)^c$.

therefore $  (a^c \times B)\cup (A \times b^c)\subseteq (a\times b)^c$

So, $(a\times b)^c = (a^c \times B)\cup (A \times b^c)$

Explanation:[image]

here $X$ axis is your set $A$ and $Y$ axis is your set $B$. and blue colour is $a$ and Red is $b$.

so the intersection of two colours region 1 is $(a\times b)$.

so $(a\times b)^c$ is 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9.
which is equal to 2+3+4+7+8+9 union 2+5+7+4+6+9.

and 2+3+4+7+8+9 is $(A \times b^c)$
and 2+5+7+4+6+9 is $(a^c \times B)$

Comment: hence * in either of those cases*

Comment: +1... I suspect that the proposer, in his/her notes, accidentally wrote  $(a^c\times b)\cup (a\times b^c),$ which is generally not equal to $(a\times b)^c$...E.g. when $A=B=\{1,2\}$ and $a=b=\{1\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I also think the same.